# Firefox always opens google.com regardless of driver.get specified

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

(Selenium 3.14, FireFox 64.0, Eclipse Photon 4.8.0, Java jdk-10.0.2)
Created test script.  It opens FireFox browser but always opens to google.com regardless of page I want to open. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
package gov.gamb.rodtests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirefoxTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {        
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Software Downloads\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org");
    }
}
```

Console data feedback/errors:

```
1537387613514   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\TERESA~1.LOC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.YwDCKs4o92QQ"
[GPU 7284, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[14224, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 232: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 513
[14224, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[GPU 2692, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file[GFX1-]: GPU process disabled after 2 attempts
[GFX1-]: [D3D11] failed to get compositor device.
[GFX1-]: [D3D11] Failed to init compositor with reason: FEATURE_FAILURE_D3D11_NO_DEVICE
[GFX1-]: Could not get a DXGI adapter
[GFX1-]: Could not get a DXGI adapter
[GFX1-]: [D3D11] failed to get compositor device.
[GFX1-]: [D3D11] Failed to init compositor with reason: FEATURE_FAILURE_D3D11_NO_DEVICE
[GFX1-]: Could not get a DXGI adapter
IPDL protocol Error: Received an invalid file descriptor
IPDL protocol Error: Received an invalid file descriptor
IPDL protocol Error: Received an invalid file descriptor
IPDL protocol Error: Received an invalid file descriptor
IPDL protocol Error: Received an invalid file descriptor
1537387616407   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 64739
1537387616806   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
1537387616879   Marionette  DEBUG   [6442450945] Frame script loaded
1537387616893   Marionette  DEBUG   [6442450945] Frame script registered
Sep 19, 2018 4:06:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1537387617035   Marionette  DEBUG   [6442450945] Received DOM event beforeunload for about:blank
1537387618516   Marionette  DEBUG   [6442450945] Received DOM event pagehide for about:blank
1537387618729   Marionette  DEBUG   [6442450945] Received DOM event DOMContentLoaded for https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
1537387620916   Marionette  DEBUG   [6442450945] Received DOM event pageshow for https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
```

Comment: Just clean the project and run it again.
And try to get the title of it using System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

Comment: Just for sure hit Win+R, enter command firefox.exe -p, run Firefox in rust_mozprofile profile and set blank start page instead of google.com.